# Need suggestions for covering up rough cut on tile above niche

Tags: bathroom, trim, tiling

DIY. Tiled everything except for the top underside of the niche. The tile on the wall above the niche has a rough cut so I was  thinking to cover up with some tiling trim. I was thinking to either mortar a Shluter Reno T trim between this area or silicone an angled corner trim. The tile on the wall above the trim hangs over the inch by about 1/4 of an inch. I bought a Shluter bullnose edge trim but unfortunately it does not work for this situation. Was seeing if anyone has any suggestions on how to cover this up. Thanks!

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Comment: Why not just finish the underside of that niche with a piece of normal wall tile?  That's what I did with a similar niche.

Comment: I don't see this as a decorating question but one of "how to do this right".

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the problem is that the bottom edge of the tile on the face above the niche is rough-cut, and the OP is looking for advice on how to make it look better.  Personally, I'd consider using a piece similar to what was used on the *bottom* of the niche and let it be a couple mm proud of the tile face.  Then use some silicone caulk (match grout color) to hide the rough edge of the tile.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe its an optical illusion.  But to me, it looks like the underneath is not tiled.  You should tile it, which may explain why the tile is jutting down.

If you dont tile and grout it, then water is going to get behind the tiles!!!